# Set up Tracing method for EGL on android

Tags: android

From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/16928bfeca8858a0acae6942fc68c14a040b92ff/opengl/libs/EGL/egl.cpp, it said, I can setup tracing method:

```
/**
 * There are three different tracing methods:
 * 1. libs/EGL/trace.cpp: Traces all functions to systrace.
 *    To enable:
 *      - set system property "debug.egl.trace" to "systrace" to trace all apps.
 * 2. libs/EGL/trace.cpp: Logs a stack trace for GL errors after each function call.
 *    To enable:
 *      - set system property "debug.egl.trace" to "error" to trace all apps.
 * 3. libs/EGL/trace.cpp: Traces all functions to logcat.
 *    To enable:
 *      - set system property "debug.egl.trace" to 1 to trace all apps.
 *      - or call setGLTraceLevel(1) from an app to enable tracing for that app.
 * 4. libs/GLES_trace: Traces all functions via protobuf to host.
 *    To enable:
 *        - set system property "debug.egl.debug_proc" to the application name.
 *      - or call setGLDebugLevel(1) from the app.
 */
```

How can I do that on an actual device?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. adb shell
2. setprop debug.egl.trace error
3. stop
4. start
5. run app

Comment: hmm.. that alone doesn't do the trick. I think the EGL libs need to compiled with these features enabled.